# Washer trips breaker at spin?

Tags: washing-machine

My GE washing machine has been working for 6 months and is now tripping switch at agitate and spin cycles.  It will not spin or agitate and mainly trips with lid closed?  IDEAS?

Comment: What's the model number on it?  And is your breaker a GFCI, AFCI, DFCI, or conventional breaker?

Comment: Model wcsr4170goww GE. And GFCI

Answer (score 1):

While I can't be 100% sure -- it sounds like the motor is pulling excessive start current and causing the breaker to trip.

Try spinning the drum by hand with the washing machine not running/empty -- if it spins freely (your washer is belt drive) then I'd start by replacing the motor/inverter assembly.

If the drum doesn't spin freely then you have a drive system problem somewhere.